# Limit as $(x,y)\to(0,0)$ of $(y-x)/xy$

Tags: limits, multivariable-calculus

Title says it all.  I don't think this limit exists, but I want some opinions.  Thanks.

$$ \lim_\limits{ x\to0 \atop y\to0 }\frac{y-x}{xy}   $$

Comment: $y_n = x_n = \frac{1}{n} \ $ gives a different result to $y_n = \frac{1}{n}, \  x_n = \frac{1}{n^2}.$ In particular, the latter diverges, so therefore no limit exists.

Comment: See: https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Limit_of_Function_by_Convergent_Sequences

and https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/886910/how-to-determine-the-existence-of-double-limit

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The limit on the line $y=x$ is $$\lim_{x\to0}\frac{x-x}{x^2}=\lim_{x\to0}\frac0{x^2}=0$$ while the limit on the line $y=2x$ is $$\lim_{x\to0}\frac{2x-x}{2x^2}=\lim_{x\to0}\frac1{2x}=DNE$$ so there is no limit.